# Is the set of irrational number discrete or continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, irrational-numbers

Reading this question and the related answers [Is the set of rational number discrete or continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468587/is-the-set-of-rational-number-discrete-or-continuous) I have come up with the question if the set of irrational number, say we call it $\mathbb{I}$, is either discrete or not.

I understood from the answers that there is actually no notion of continuous / discrete for a set, so I'm maybe wrong already in using the terminology.

I also understood that, reading about the rational set, that "it depends on the topology we use".
Can I use the same arguments of the accepted answer for proving the set $\mathbb{I}$ is not discrete?

Also, bypassing the wrong terminology, could saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete recall the notion of non-open and non-closed in set theory? Like $\mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete but it's not continuous either.

Thank you so much for the patience.

Comment: It would probably help if you gave a definition of what YOU mean by "discrete", because the term has various meanings I believe. In particular, it would help if you were completely explicit as to whether you are considering the irrational numbers as a topological space (most likely I suspect), or as a linearly ordered set, or as something else.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I'm considering the set of irrationals in the same way of $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, I know the irrational set is a dense set, in the same way $\mathbb{Q}$ is. By applying the definition of discrete topological space (the same the guy gives in the accepted answer), I would say $\mathbb{I}$ is non discrete too. Clearly here too with the inherited topology from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The notion of an isolated point depends on the topology being considered. Neither set is discrete with the usual topology, both are with the discrete topology.

Comment: @copper.hat So if equip the usual topology, I can use the same argument of that answer to show irrational space is not discrete, right?

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, a question: why is not $\mathbb{N}$ discrete with the usual topology? Sorry for bothering

Comment: I did not read the other answer, but presumably it is.

Comment: The natural numbers are discrete with the usual topology. Why do you say otherwise?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: As Qiaochu Yuan explains in his answer, the answer to your title question is No.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a reason we don't use the word "continuous" to describe spaces in mathematics, and it's exactly because of situations like this. The language of [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) has more precise terms for describing what's going on here: both the irrational and rational numbers, equipped with their [subspace topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology), are

- [totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) (so they are *nowhere* "continuous") but
- have no [isolated points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) (so they are also *nowhere* [discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), which has a standard and rigorous meaning in topology).

Loosely speaking they can both be thought of as "fractal dust"; points in the dust are not isolated from other points but the points don't "continuously" connect to each other either (e.g. there are no continuous [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)) from any point to any other point). The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is also like this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Enlightening!